# SQL - Denormalization

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to familiarize myself with a new database that is structured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [TableA] (ID int not null, Primary Key (ID))
CREATE TABLE [TableB] (ID int not null, Primary Key (ID))
CREATE TABLE [TableC] (ID int not null, ID2 int, ID3 int, ID4 int, primary key (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ID2) REFERENCES TableA(ID), FOREIGN KEY (ID3) REFERENCES TableB(ID))
```

Table C is a many to many junction table between tableA and tableB.  TableC.ID is unique (as it is a Primary Key).  TableC.ID4 is also unique and does not seem to refer to anything.  I contacted the developer who described it as a "denormalization of the M1 (many to 1) entity".  I fully understand the purpose of dernormalization (normalizing a database and then intentionally introducing anomalies for performance reasons), however I still do not understand the reasoning behind this.  Is there a pattern or concept that I am unaware of? The application is written in C++ with a bit of VB.NET.

Comment: He calls this _'denormalization'_?  These kind of tables (`TableC`) is usually used as cross-references between many-to-many relationships, not many-to-one (which is usually solved with a simple FK in the child table). `TableC.id` is pointless, assuming the tuple [`TableC.id1`, `TableC.id2`] is unique (which then is the primary key instead).  If `TableC.id4` doesn't have any relevant data, it should be removed (don't add 'unused' attributes ahead of time, YAGNI).  Maybe we could get some more information?

Answer (score 0):

It's fair denormalization if     tableC.ID4 contains values that ordinarily you'd have to perform an additional join or lookup for. So have you checked the application code to see what that column is being populated for? If it doesn't refer to anything and doesn't provide any enrichment to the row data as a whole, you may safely move on with your development.

Comment: can you suggest what the field could be used for? I would have thought that the Primary Key was enough as it is unique.

Comment: Suggest to you what to use the column for? No I can't. Anything I say here is pure presumption: It's possible that the ID4 field is in fact a reference to another pk in another table in the same schema, the prev dev just decided not to slap formal a foreign key constraint on the column. I think the question you should ask the previous dev is **_what table/entity_** exactly is ID4 a ref to. Or if you can walk back from the app insert code for that particular table and discover what is used to populate that field.

Comment: From the explanation he gave you, the column was just introduced so he doesn't have to go look elsewhere for that particular value. So he's gotta tell you where "elsewhere" is

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer per se, just a related thought. Please don't start down voting it.

Is there any sort of link between tableC.ID and tableC.ID4 ? In one of my projects I had similar case - I was having userid and username in user table. Both were unique with userid as primary key. There is one way to remove username from that table and reate a separate table mapping userid to username. I am not a great fan of normalization. So I thought its an overhead to fire a join query every time I need data from user table containing username and kept my design as it is.

Comment: If this is not an answer, why didn't you make it a comment?

Comment: that may not be a perfect answer.